# Search and download all pdf in my bucket (boto3 python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to get all the pdf's contained in my buckets and then process them.
I tried this:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    mybucket = bucket.name
    for obj in mybucket.objects.filter(Prefix='.pdf'):
        print(obj)
```

But I get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually create [Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket) object:

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    mybucket = bucket.name
    for obj in s3r.Bucket('mybucket').objects.filter(Prefix='.pdf'):
        print(obj)
```

But your `Prefix='.pdf'` will probably not work anyway, as `.pdf` is suffix, not prefix. So better to do:

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    mybucket = bucket.name
    for obj in s3r.Bucket('mybucket').objects.all():
        if obj.key.endswith('.pdf'):
            print(f"download and process the {obj.key}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact I had to search for the keys that end with '.pdf'...